# Is it possible to fetch the data from two data source in Apache Superset?

Tags: mysql, apache-superset

Is it possible to fetch the data from two data source in **Apache Superset**? For e.g having sql query which fetch the records from **MySql** and **Salesforce** on which the slice can be generated.

Answer (score 1):

- I will ask for more clarification on this, do you mean to have 2 databases for querying in a single SQL query ? , Like a federated query
  `select * from mysql.___ inner join salesforce.___ on ….` something like this ? , If this is the case, currently unfortunately Superset does not supports it.
- Salesforce has lots of products, so can you please clarify which specific DB from Salesforce you are talking about ? And at the moment there is unfortunately now none salesforce's product DB supported.